# Convert nested list sourced using reticulate to data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, type-conversion, reticulate

I am using the `source_python` function from `reticulate` to import data into my R environment. The resulting nested list looks quite different than the ones created natively in R. I would be glad if anyone could help me convert this list to data frame.

You can refer here for additional information including type conversions on `reticulate`: [rstudio/reticulate](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate)

```
dput(my_list)
# list(list(A = 4658913, B = <environment>, C = "chr1", D = <environment>, 
#     E = <environment>, F = <environment>, G = FALSE, H = <environment>, 
#     I = <environment>, J = TRUE, K = "3958"), list(A = 78510, 
#     B = <environment>, C = "chr2", D = <environment>, E = <environment>, 
#     F = <environment>, G = TRUE, H = <environment>, I = <environment>, 
#     J = FALSE, K = "3620"))

class(my_list[[1]]$B)
# [1] "decimal.Decimal"       "python.builtin.object"

str(my_list)
# List of 2
#  $ :List of 11
#   ..$ A: num 4658913
#   ..$ B:7
#   ..$ C: chr "chr1"
#   ..$ D:254.9254204664572
#   ..$ E:-36
#   ..$ F:2549
#   ..$ G: logi FALSE
#   ..$ H:81
#   ..$ I:0
#   ..$ J: logi TRUE
#   ..$ K: chr "3958"
#  $ :List of 11
#   ..$ A: num 78510
#   ..$ B:20
#   ..$ C: chr "chr2"
#   ..$ D:823.4090235114015
#   ..$ E:6359
#   ..$ F:-5231
#   ..$ G: logi TRUE
#   ..$ H:229
#   ..$ I:0
#   ..$ J: logi FALSE
#   ..$ K: chr "3620"

my_list[[1]]
# $A
# [1] 4658913

# $B
# 7

# $C
# [1] "chr1"

# $D
# 254.9254204664572

# $E
# -36

# $F
# 2549

# $G
# [1] FALSE

# $H
# 81

# $I
# 0

# $J
# [1] TRUE

# $K
# [1] "3958"
```